# Stackoverflows Tags system, How To

Tags: php, mysql, tags, foreign-keys

OK so now I can understand that SO's search system is primarily based around tags, the tag system they use is a very good one at that but what I want to do is replicate it for my own projects.

Now I can understand how to use foreign keys and such, but I'm not exactly sure how it's been developed here, do they use 3 tables or 2 etc.

How have they developed it, can you show me some MySql examples?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539744/best-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152850/best-way-to-store-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO considers questions and answers to be the same thing - a `Post`.  Here's a stripped down MySQL equivalent table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`post`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`post` (
  `postid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`postid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Tags are stored in a typical type code table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`tags`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`tags` (
  `tagid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `tagname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tagid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Associating a tag to a question/post is recorded in the database in a many-to-many table - in SO, it's called `POSTTAGS`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`posttags`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`posttags` (
  `postid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `tagid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`postid`,`tagid`),
  KEY `fk_tag` (`tagid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_post` FOREIGN KEY (`postid`) REFERENCES `post` (`postid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tag` FOREIGN KEY (`tagid`) REFERENCES `tags` (`tagid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The `POSTTAGS` table:

- is only two columns, and those columns are the primary key - this makes sure there can't be duplicates, and that either side (post or tag) can never be NULL.
- The foreign key requires that the data stored in the table must already exist in the respective foreign table...

If you ever want to look at the SO schema, [check out the Stack Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) - when you compose a query, the SO schema is available on the righthand side.

Comment: thanks for the answer, im going threw it now doing my own samples see what i can do with it! thansk