# Differentiating between a question and answer

Tags: sql, mysql

From this question: [Stackoverflows Tags system, How To](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542128/stackoverflows-tags-system-how-to)

> SO considers questions and answers to
>   be the same thing - a Post.

A question has a title, whereas a reply does not, how does SO deal with this? What would the table structure be?

How do you differentiate between a question and an answer and what would go in the title field for a answer? Can you show me what this would look like in MySQL?

Comment: Is your question about how it *could* be done or about how *was* it done on SE sites?

Comment: You may be interested in http://data.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this is a problem of object-oriented inheritance and its mapping to relational model used by databases like MySQL (or MS SQL in case of SO).

You can find more resources about that if you search using these keywords. I'll just give you a short list of different approaches to the problem:

1. You can use one big table for all posts, and then have the values for `title` column have `null` value for answers. Good for performance, no need to have too many joins, too much unused data.
2. You can have all different tables with redundant columns for shared properties. Good for performance, no extra joins, no `null` values using up space, some redundant code, though.
3. You can have a separate table for the shared properties called say `post` and a table for each subtype `questions`, `answers` etc. No `null` values, no redundant code, but must use SQL joins for just about anything, theoretically cleanest as it is normalized (academic world seems to love that), but for large amount of data simply useless.

Which particular strategy was chosen for SO, I don't know. Maybe someone of the mods would care to answer that.

Comment: Thats what I had a problem with, I though having a title column that is null half the time would be a mistake.

Comment: @john: It's not a mistake. It's just one possible decision with both good and bad sides.

Comment: I tried #3 and if you put authors into the equation and tags and you want to get all that data at one, thats a boatload of joins I had to use.

Comment: @john: for joins: exactly! for getting all the data at once: if you haven't already look into paging queries using `offset` and `limit`, and also lazy loading. May help you a bit with that problem.

Comment: Yeah I was using limit, its just because of the amount of jokes I though there had to be an easier way