# Correct way to set up MYSQL database for related tag searches?

Tags: php, mysql

I have people uploading art on my site. They enter titles, tags, and the file.

Once it's uploaded i have tags the title, tags separated by commas and the filepath for converted image file.

I now want to find closest related art by tags to this one. So to find closest match I have to  explode the tags and search for each individual one? It seems like a lot of work on the server. I was wondering can anyone tell me what's the correct way to store the tags and data and what search would I have to do?

Would I have to have one table that holds the title, and filepath and another table to hold id of the art and a column of one of the tags. Meaning if I have "pencil, animal, wildlife" I'd have three rows in the tags table with the same art ID ?

Comment: Yes your last paragraph is correct read up on normalisation. [Specifically first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). You should never store delimited multiple values in the same column that you then need to split to perform queries on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to store tags in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539744/best-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate out your data entities by what they are and what they mean.  For `title`, `tags` and `file` it sounds like you have two entities:

```
Picture
----------
ID
Title
File

Tag
----------
ID
Name
```

That is, the `title` and the `file` (in your case I guess you're storing that as the path to the file on the file system, which is fine) are one entity, and a `tag` is its own separate entity.  Since each `Picture` can have multiple `tag`s and each `tag` can relate to multiple `Picture`s, it's a many-to-many relationship.  So one would generally create a supporting non-entity table to link them in the database:

```
PictureTagRelationship
----------
PictureID
TagID
```

With this, you can get a `Picture`:

```
SELECT Picture.Title, Picture.File FROM Picture WHERE Picture.ID = ?id
```

and its tags:

```
SELECT Tag.ID, Tag.Name FROM Tag
INNER JOIN PictureTagRelationship ON Tag.ID = PictureTagRelationship.TagID
WHERE PictureTagRelationship.PictureID = ?id
```

(You can do that in a single query in a couple of ways as well, I just split it into two for simplicity.  Two queries shouldn't be a big deal, but if you need to highly optimize your database access overhead or if you really want it to be a single query then I'm sure something can be done.)

Or you can get all the pictures for a specific tag:

```
SELECT Picture.ID, Picture.Title, Picture.File FROM Picture
INNER JOIN PictureTagRelationship ON Picture.ID = PictureTagRelationship.PictureID
WHERE PictureTagRelationship.TagID = ?id
```

There are other tweaks that can be made to this design and plenty of other ways to view and report on the data.  But in all of this is one key point:

**Don't use comma-delimited lists to store data.**  Normalize each data entity into its own structure and store it accordingly.  Relational databases are great for that sort of thing.  But any time you store separate data elements as a delimited string, you lose that separation of those elements.  This makes it more difficult to report on that data, more difficult to interact with it, a *lot* more difficult to update it, and less intuitive to anybody else who needs to support it.

Just remember that any one field in the database should be storing one piece of information and *only* one piece of information.  If you have to cram multiple pieces of information into a single field then you're not using the relational database properly.

Comment: what if the images are being uploaded dynamically by the members? Do I check for the tags if they exist or do I create duplicate entries of the tag in the tags table?

Comment: @Darius: If the tag exists, just link the image to that tag.  If it doesn't exist (and people are able to create tags), create the new tag and link it.  One approach I've taken for that in the past (where an object is always assumed to exist because if it doesn't it should be created) is to have a DAL method which always returns an instance of the requested object (in this case a tag).  Within that method is the `SELECT` to find it and either return it or `INSERT` a new one and return that.  So outside the method is appears as though every tag ever requested exists.