# Fastest way to sort through 'tagging' DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, tagging

I had a fairly commonplace tagging system set up:

```
table|'keyword'|   : tag_id        | tag
table|'tag_thread'|: tag_thread_id | tag_id      | thread_id
table|'thread'|    : thread_id     | thread_info
```

However, I have since changed the way my tagging will be displayed.

My new idea is to have a `related` column in the `keyword_tbl`. I decided to try this route because I wanted to do a breadcrumb system, and would like to 'order' the tags, for instance, Sports -> baseball -> pitchers.  Also, if they type in "baseball" i'd like to include Sports as part of tags without them worrying about it.

```
keyword_tbl : keyword_id | keyword | related_id
```

For example:

```
keyword_tbl:
keyword_id // 1       // 2        // 3
keyword    // sports  // baseball // pitchers
related    // 0       // 1        // 2
```

`0` marks the fact that it is a 'general' tag, being the most broadest term. This means for each thread that they post, I would only need to store a single value (the most detailed, or "pitcher" in the above example).  Starting with "Pitcher" I could derive the related fields, and create the breadcrumbs in a backwards manner.

My question is this: Which route would be better for what I'm trying to do with the breadcrumbs?  Is there something particularly wrong with the way I'm planning on doing it that someone can see?

Thanks

Comment: [look here looks same post as yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221196/correct-way-to-set-up-mysql-database-for-related-tag-searches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some potential problems (but this doesn't mean you are on the wrong track).

Generally, tags are a looser concept than categories.  It sounds like you are mixing them together, which may be a problem.  What is going to happen when you have a tag (let's say, "left handers") that applies to people in Baseball and Football?  Tags were invented to avoid this kind of classification problem, where everything needs one parent in a tree.

The query to figure out the set of related tags is likely to be inefficient/messy, depending on how many levels of breadcrumbs you may have.  Who is in charge of classifying the tags into a tree?  If it's an admin function (therefore doesn't happen too often) you may want to create a "materialized view" that will hold all the related tags of each tag.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  To answer your question, the user will have the ability to create their own tags. The problem with the tagging system as you described, involving the 'left handers' is that if the user was looking at the 'left handers' tag, and creates a post, there is no way to classify it under "Baseball," "football" or "Sports," as well.  That is the problem im trying to overcome.

Comment: That was my point -- tagging and classifying are not very compatible as concepts, regardless of the implementation.  Have you seen them mixed together like that successfully?  I'm curious because both are useful, I just can't see how to use them together.  You can have separate tags and categories, but that sounds like extra work for your users.

Comment: interesting.  I'll get back to you on that.  For now, i'll mark this as correct.  Though not the answer I was looking for, certainly an informative one that will help me evolve the concept.