# Handling Tags in database

Tags: php, mysql

My website contains videos and they contain tags, I'm not sure how to store the whole thing in the database.
I tried this way:

```
Table: Videos
Columns: video_id, title, tagsList
Indexes: video_id

Table: Tag
Columns: video_id, tagTitle
Indexes: video_id, tagTitle
```

The problem is that I have over 100k videos and each one of them has around 10 tags so my Tag table has 1M rows. So if I want to print all of the tags and the amount of videos for each one of them it takes unreasonable time.

Comment: I don't see why you would need the `tagList` column in the video table? Instead add a separate linking table that contains the linkage betweens a tag_id and a video_id and then remove change your `tag` table to `tag_id` and `tagTitle` or something like this. To increase loading time perhaps you should **not** load 100k video at once?

Comment: Might want to check this out [Correct way to set up MySQL database for related tag searches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221196/correct-way-to-set-up-mysql-database-for-related-tag-searches?rq=1)

Comment: @Cyclone I don't load 100k at once, but displaying the tag list and the amount of videos for each tags requires me to scan all the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we have to define problem. So here I see two concerns

1. Database structure
2. Performance for accessing informations

---

1. For Database you can actually created pivot table for tags collections as kitten posted.

`` CREATE TABLE `video_tag` (
      `video_id` int not null,
      `tag_id` int not null,
      `added` datetime not null,
      INDEX `main` (`tag_id` asc, `added` asc),
      INDEX `video` (`video_id` asc)
    ); ``

the case here is to have good index that will provide you as fast as possible information.

2. About getting essential informations:

   - First of all I'd ask myself that can I preload couple tags, and load more on click `more` button or something. It is not convenient way to fetch all tags because not all could be read by user / system at the time.
   - If the performance of getting all tags is not acceptable do I use a reliable technology to achieve that ? Maybe storing all tags with mongo database (https://www.mongodb.com) would provide me better performance on that
   - If I need counters I'd go with materialized view, when I can proceed all aggregations processes triggered by event (add tag to movie, etc.) to be stored in this view without need to counting all of them on runtime.

a) So as a conclusion, regarding on your informations. I would preload couple tags, and then fetch more if needed.
b) I would create materialized view. Table

`` CREATE TABLE `mv_movies_tags_counter` (
      `video_id` int not null,
      `count` int not null,
      INDEX `video` (`video_id` asc)
    ); ``

and update counter on event: add/remove tag from movie. So that could be triggered automaticaly by mysql trigger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER inc_tags_counter AFTER INSERT ON video_tag
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE mv_movies_tags_counter SET count = count + 1 WHERE video_id = NEW.video_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER inc_tags_counter AFTER DELETE ON video_tag
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE mv_movies_tags_counter SET count = count - 1 WHERE video_id = NEW.video_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Pivot table instead. So you have something like this

```
Table: Videos
Columns: video_id, title, tagsList
Indexes: video_id

Table: Tag
Columns: tag_id, tagTitle
Indexes: tag_id

Table: video_tag
Columns: video_id, tag_id
Indexes: tag_id,video_id
```

Then make the columns on video_tag a foreign key and reference the column on each of the tables

Comment: How is it different? the table video_tag will have videos*tags amount of rows like my implementation. doesn't it?

Comment: Correction: Amount of Videos * Average amount of Tags per Video.

Comment: You have a n:m relation. A Video can have muliple Tags, and a Tag is in multiple Videos.
So instead of writing the Tags directly in the Video Table, you define a new Table with the Relations.
You can then grab all Tags of a Video
 (SELECT Tag_ID From Video_Tag WHERE Video_ID=x)
And you can easily grab all Video IDS with that Tag:
 (SELECT Video_ID From Video_Tag WHERE Tag_ID=x)

Answer (score 1):

You can always make the queries faster by making the data modification a bit slower :)
The good thing in the answer of  @T alagbe is that if the connector table contains only the 2 ID fields, then it has a low memory footprint. But I think this is not enough.

I would extend that connector table with the field by which you sort the videos. For example if the videos are sorted by the date they were added, then:

```
CREATE TABLE `video_tag` (
  `video_id` int not null,
  `tag_id` int not null,
  `added` datetime not null,
  INDEX `main` (`tag_id` asc, `added` asc),
  INDEX `video` (`video_id` asc)
);
```

Notice that the important thing is the composite index "main". You could even remove the other index from this table. You can have multiple tables like this, but then every time someone adds or removes a video, you would have to update them.
What also can speed up cases like this are sparse indexes. But those are not supported in MySQL (AFAIK).

UPDATE: What you can also consider, is to cache video lists for specific filterings. These could be updated by a crontab task in every 10-30 minutes.

Comment: How is it more efficient from what I'm doing now?. I didn't understand your first sentence can you please give more details? :)